# How to sort NSArray of custom objects by a specific property in descending order?

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray, compare

How do I make this piece of code to order in descending order. This code always gives me the array in ascending order:

```
NSArray *sortedProductsByStyle = [unsortedProducts sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(Product *p1, Product *p2) {
        return [p1.productStyle compare:p2.productStyle options:NSNumericSearch];
    }];
```

I thought that using NSOrderedDescending would work but it didn't:

```
NSArray *sortedProductsByStyle = [unsortedProducts sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(Product *p1, Product *p2) {
        return [p1.productStyle compare:p2.productStyle options:NSNumericSearch | NSOrderedDescending];
    }];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is a type of "productStyle" ?

Comment: It is of type NSString but only holds number data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about just inverting the compare order?

```
NSArray *sortedProductsByStyle = [unsortedProducts sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(Product *p1, Product *p2) {
    return [p2.productStyle compare:p1.productStyle options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

Comment: I tested it, and in this particular escenario it actually works. Let's see what happens when is not a numeric search, i think is going to work too, though. Thank you very much Gabriele!

Comment: `NSNumericSearch` changes the result of the compare, according to the type (which you didn't specify in your question). That said, inverting the comparison order will always invert the final result order ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this way...

```
sortedArray = [unsortedProducts sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(Product p1 , Product p2) {
            return [((NSString *)p1.productStyle) compare:((NSString *)p2.productStyle) options:NSNumericSearch];
        }];
```

Let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: Why should the cast help?

Comment: I think you are confused about what casting does.

Comment: 1. if productStyle is an integer, the original code won't even compile.  2. Casting **does not** change the type of the object, it just makes the compiler believe it is a `NSString`, but at runtime it changes nothing.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella, i know it just consider as a string.

Comment: Adding a cast, as you propose, changes **nothing** if `productStyle` is a `NSString` and it's just **wrong** and potentially **dangerous** if it's not.

Comment: My custom objects only contain NSString properties, so i don't think explicitly casting to NSString is going to make any difference since they are already strings, but i appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Also, as I said already, if they weren't strings it would have been dangerous to cast them as such.